# How can we expand one model data in to another controller in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

How can we expand one model data to check condition  in to another controller in cakephp ?

eg:

```
   class UsersController extends AppController
{
public function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->loadModel('Apages');
    $usr=$this->Apages->find('all');
    $this->loadModel('Pagepermissions');
    $pre=$this->Pagepermissions->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>'1')));

if($pre->request->data['Pagepermissions']['_add']==1)
    {
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'add'));
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotFoundException(__("Don't have access this Page"));
    }
}

}
```

in this code

`$pre->request->data['Pagepermissions']['_add']` is showing error.
Please suggest me how to do that

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

$pre is array , do something like

```
$pre=$this->Pagepermissions->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>'1')));
 if(!empty($pre)){
    foreach($pre as $v){
        if($v['Pagepermissions']['_add']==1){
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'add'));
            return;
        }else{
           throw new NotFoundException(__("Don't have access this Page"));
        }
    }
}else{
   throw new NotFoundException(__("user not find"));
}
```